# QGIS Custom form

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to create a custom form in QGIS. Unfortunately I can't manage to disconnect the ButtonBox signals. (Save / Cancel). The form should not close until a condition matches.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def open(dialog, layer, feature):

    dialog.disconnectButtonBox()
    buttonBox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")
    lineEdit = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEdit")
    buttonBox.accepted.connect(save(dialog, lineEdit))
    buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.resetValues)



def save(dialog, lineEdit):
    if lineEdit.text() != 'keyword':
        dialog.accept()
```

I get the following error message:

```
open( _qgis_featureform, _qgis_layer, _qgis_feature)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 11, in open
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the ui?